# Why is the Earth considered an infinite electron source or sink?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

All the literature I've read says that Earth is pretty much an infinite electron source/sink.

If you add or remove electrons from the earth, then the charge of the earth must change. Furthermore, the amount of Coulombs it changes by is the same as if you removed it from a small ball or a tree or really anything else.

So what makes Earth different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What makes it different is that the earth is really, really big. This means you can pull or push lots of charge into or out of some region of it it without altering the voltage it holds by any measurable amount.

Comment: Ok. I want to make sure I'm understanding this. Consider this scenario. You have the Earth and then you magically add a ton of electrons to it. Then a metal wire connects to the Earth and then disconnects. In this scenario, do you have reverse grounding, where the wire has an overall negative charge after it disconnects?

Comment: it would pick up a tiny excess of electrons, but the sheer number of electrons in your magic "ton" would have to be enormous to have this effect.

Comment: Ok. So is this is why reverse grounding doesn't happen in real life? Because nothing on Earth is comparable to the Earth in terms of volume?

Comment: yes. Try writing the equation for the earth as a spherical capacitor!

Comment: @TypicalHighschooler Changing the potential of the earth by adding or subtracting any amount of charge that you will ever encounter (including lightning!) of is like changing the color of the earth as seen from space by peeing in the ocean.